# Создание Базы данных и запросов к ней

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Нужно создать БД в которой есть  таблица Кружок( есть название, адрес, макс. количество детей), таблица Тренер, который может вести несколько кружков( у него есть Имя, Фамилия, Номер телефона). Спортивная школа, в которой есть несколько кружков, а также есть тренера( по атрибутам:Адрес, номер телефона). Група детей(Название, время начала/конца занятий). Собственно, сами Занятия( атрибуты: Група, Время начала, Продолжительность). А также сами Групы Детей(Имя, Фамилия, номер телефона).

Так вот с создание базы вопросов нету. Есть некоторые сложности с созданием запросов для обработки информации в этой базе:
Нужны скрипты для просмотра:
1.Самих кружков, сгрупированы по Спорт.Школах
2.Создание новых Груп детей, с указанием Кружка, Спорт.Школы и тренеров.
3.Создание розписания для для Групы, указав все Занятия.
Должно все быть для MySQL

Кто может, помогите пожалуйста, заранее спасибо!

Comment: приведите пример SQL-запросов (кода), с которыми возникают проблемы

Comment: Эти вот три запроса, что я и указал в выше

Comment: 1.Самих кружков, сгрупированы по Спорт.Школах 2.Создание новых Груп детей, с указанием Кружка, Спорт.Школы и тренеров. 3.Создание розписания для для Групы, указав все Занятия.